# Xcode doesn't export strings from xibs for localization

Tags: xcode, localization, internationalization

I'm trying to follow [Apple's localization guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html) with my project, but after I select Editor -> Export for Localization, the resulting .xliff file doesn't contain any strings from .xib files.
It has only strings from Localizable.strings and from Info.plist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did it!

Turns out, it was a project created in old Xcode version that doesn't support Base Internationalization.
I had to

- Press “Localize” on all the xibs in the project
- Then go to Project Settings and in the Info tab check “Use Base Internationalization” checkmark.

After this, the resulting .xliff file has all the .xib strings.